# React js маршрутизация

Tags: javascript, reactjs, route

У меня два блока на главной странице, и у каждого блока свой меню. Меню главной страницы работает с помощью react-router-dom... но как организовать работы блочных менюшек? Ведь route меняет url, а мне нужно, чтобы переходы были внутри блока...даже не знаю какой код тут показывать,но надеюсь вопрос понятен... Прошу помочь.

Comment: А в чем проблема просто скрывать и открывать нужные тебе списки?

Comment: Так меняет url главной страницы и в итоге получается конфликт между двумя блоками... Главный меню на уровне App, а блоки то вложенные

Comment: Ну если тебе нужны переходы внутри блока - роутинг это точно не твой выбор. react-router-dom работает на базе history. А history у тебя только одно на странице. Нужно писать свой солюшин для этой задачи. Я бы рекомендовал просто скрывать и открывать нужные тебе елементы внутри блока

Comment: У меня около сто стихов в блоке, должно быть - нажимаю на название - стих открывается в блоке, не меняя страницу. Прошу чуть конкретнее посоветовать как это организовать, спасибо заранее.

Comment: Это не понятный вопрос. Опишите более конкретно вашу проблему

Comment: Открываем главную страницу сайта. Там есть левый блок, и правый блок. Левый блок имеет список названий стихов, а правый - для одного стишка. Я хочу нажать на название стихотворения и чтоб правый блок показал данный стих. При этом не меняя главный url страницы.... Если было бы 5-6 стихов, я бы это организовал с помощью display: block и none... но тут куча стихов, как это грамотно реализовать?

Comment: А от куда вы получаете эти стихи?

Comment: сам создаю в файлах, может стоит в блоках?

Comment: Всымсле в фаликах? Их тебе бекенд отдает?

Comment: Нет, сам создаю в реакте

Comment: Вам не кажется, что вы не правильно используете реакт?

Comment: Я только учусь, прошу более подробно описать в чем я не прав

Comment: Реакт предполагает то, что контент будет динамически рендериться. Данные по хорошему должны получаться с бекенда у виде json. В нем не нужно писать всю разметку как в html

Comment: Бекенд это работа с сервером, стихи должны быть взяты из сервера, что ли? Я понимаю суть реакта, но выходить я часть сайта должен написать на реакте, а часть -на джкуери? Например есть блок комментарий, диалогов, новостей - это все реакт, а статичческая часть на обычном? Так будет правильно разве?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понял что нужна навигация на react-router-dom.
Решением может быть:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const ItemList = ({ history }) => {
  const arr = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Title1",
        text:
            "1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque 
    corrupti optio ipsam, libero tempora cum quis dolor qui, nisi amet placeat fugiat? 
    Architecto ea nihil ipsam ratione praesentium nostrum necessitatibus!"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "Title2",
        text:
            "2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque 
    corrupti optio ipsam, libero tempora cum quis dolor qui, nisi amet placeat fugiat? 
    Architecto ea nihil ipsam ratione praesentium nostrum necessitatibus!"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "Title3",
        text:
            "3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque 
    corrupti optio ipsam, libero tempora cum quis dolor qui, nisi amet placeat fugiat? 
    Architecto ea nihil ipsam ratione praesentium nostrum necessitatibus!"
    }
];

const handleItemClick = ({ title, text }) =>
    history.push("/info", { title, text });

return (
    <div className="itemList">
        {arr.map(({ id, title, text }) => (
            <div
                className="item"
                onClick={() => handleItemClick({ title, text })}
                key={id}
                style={{
                    border: "1px solid grey",
                    margin: "1rem",
                    padding: "1rem",
                    width: "10rem"
                }}
            >
                {title}
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const Info = ({
  location: {
    state: { title, text }
  }
}) => {
  return (
    <div
        className="info"
        style={{
            border: "1px solid grey",
            margin: "1rem",
            padding: "1rem"
        }}
    >
        <h3>{title}</h3>
        <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
            <Route path="/" component={ItemList} />
            <Route path="/info" component={Info} />
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Если выше по иерархии раутов есть компоненты то нужно добавить их в путь.
Или чтобы не менялся URL не использовать react-router